# Form Button Redirect URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I have a form with a text field and a submit button. Also a JS which checks the input on the text field - if wrong nothing happens, if correct the button redirects the page. I had it working with the url attached to the form as an action. However, I want to have it as part of the script so the url is not visible in the source. Tried many options but somehow can't make it work.When pressing the button (with the correct input) the page itself gets reloaded instead of redirected. These are the script and the form codes any suggestions are welcomed:

```
  // JavaScript Document
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x !== "4") {
    return false;
  }
else {
window.location = 'mypage.html', true;
    
  }
}
```

&

```
<div id="form">
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<input id="answer" type="text" name="fname"><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and this was the version that used to work (without the last part of the java):

```
<div id="form">
<form name="myForm" action="mypage.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<input id="answer" type="text" name="fname"><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: As far as i understand, you're not being redirected to the page when your form is validated. Right?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Comment: did you try `window.location.href = 'mypage.html'` ?

Comment: Yes, just refreshes the page :(

Answer (score 0):

Below are some of the ways which you can use in your method:
case :1 When you want to redirect to a new page and don't allow the user to navigate to the original page

```
window.location.replace("url");
```

This function remove entry from the history

case :2 When you want to redirect to a new page and also allow the user to navigate to the original page

```
window.location.assign("url");
```

This function adds a new URL to the history stack and redirected to the new URL

you can also refer this :

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-auto-redirect-to-another-page

I hope it works.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the same problem occurs. The Page gets reloaded instead of redirected :(

Comment: can you please remove on submit from the next page?

Comment: Then it refreshes the page every time I press submit (no mater the text value)

Comment: I still have a doubt as you are using plain js so in all the cases your page will be redirected to new page and URL got change then why you don't want to use action in form ?

Comment: It is a step up kind of situation. For the user to unlock the next page they need to enter the correct information on the previous page. Therefore I don't want them to be able to see the link straight in the source code - so they can't copy/paste it that easy.

Comment: why don't you use something like this with single form [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps) I think it  should fulfill your requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216339/discussion-between-nitesh-sharma-and-hristo-hristov).

Comment: I ended up working around it with a script that automatically redirects to the new page once you input the right value in the text field (without pressing submit). Still have no idea what was wrong with the previous code, spent 4 hours playing around with those 10 lnes ...